# AngularJS template doesn't pull data from controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

*Angular version 1

On my index.html:

```
(include js files with <script>)
...
<statbox></statbox>
...
```

On js/app.js

```
var app = angular.module('buttonMasher', ['dashboard']);
```

On js/dashboard/dashboard.module.js

```
var dashboardModule = angular.module('dashboard', []);
```

On js/dashboard/statbox.component.js

```
angular.
    module('dashboard').
    component('statbox', {
      templateUrl: 'templates/dashboard/statbox.template.html',
      controller: this.statbox = [
                                {
                                    "key1" : "value1",
                                    "key2" : "value2"
                                }
                         ]
       });
```

On templates/dashboard/statbox.template.html

```
<div id="statbox">
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in statbox">
    <td>{{key}}</td> <td> {{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

If I load index.html I only see {{key}} {{value}}. What do I need to do in order to see key1 value1 and key2 value2 ?

Comment: Your controller should be a function

Answer (score 0):

Controller should be a function (credit goes to @ndoes)
Also, use $ctrl instead of this inside the html template.